# How to avoid using withColumn iteratively in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently, we have a code that has iterative usage of withColumn. When-Otherwise Conditional check & we do arithmetic computations on top of that.

Sample Code:

```
df.withColumn("col4", when(col("col1")>10, col("col2").+col("col3")).otherwise(col("col2")))
```

Other arithmetic computations happens iteratively for another 40 Columns.
Total Record Count - 2M.

**Code that is reiterated:**

```
  df.withColumn(colName1, when((col(amountToSubtract).<("0")) && (col(colName1).===("0")) && (col(amountToSubtract).<=(col(colName2))) && (col(colName2).!==("0")), col(colName2)).otherwise(col(colName1))).
      withColumn(amountToSubtract, when(col(amountToSubtract).!==("0"), col(amountToSubtract).-(col(colName2))).otherwise(col(amountToSubtract))).
      withColumn(colName1, when((col(amountToSubtract).>("0")) && (col(colName1).===("0")), col(colName2).+(col(amountToSubtract))).otherwise(col(colName1))).
      withColumn(amountToSubtract, when((col(amountToSubtract).>("0")) && (col(colName1).===("0")), "0").otherwise(col(amountToSubtract)))
```

This is followed for 7 or 8 other sets of computation.

And the job hangs at this point for a longer time. Sometimes it throws GC overhead error.
Being aware that iterative usage of .withColumn does not benefit performance, I could not find an alternative to implement these above mentioned conditional checks. Kindly assist.

Comment: you can use a foldleft and add the columns if they have the same logic. You take the list of the columns and apply a foldleft with your dataframe as the zero element. Inside the foldleft you apply a withColumn method.

Comment: @firas Thanks for the input! The code snippet that I have mentioned as reiterated is one block. And the same block of 4 withColumns is used for another 8 times. So, I find it hard to implement it using FoldLeft. If you can please share a sample foldleft for my sample code - I may extend it further.

Comment: I posted the answer. if it helps, can you mark it as good. if it's not tell me and I'll try to update.

Comment: @firas Havent tried your solution. Coz I have tried the other solution provided here since UDFs are more familiar for me. Will be trying your suggestion next week. Will keep you posted on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try encapsulating all the logic that you currently implement with 'when/otherwise' into one UDF that takes as input an array of all the column values that you need to consider when generating your new column values,  and returns as output an array of all the generated column values.    Udfs sometimes have their own performance issues, but it might be worth a shot.  Here's a simple illustration of the technique I am thinking of:

```
object SO extends App {

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("simple").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  import sparkSession.implicits._

  case class Record(col1: Int, col2: Int, amtToSubtract: Int)

  val recs = Seq(
    Record(1, 2, 3),
    Record(11, 2, 3)
  ).toDS()


  val colGenerator : Seq[Int] => Seq[Int] =
    (arr: Seq[Int]) =>  {
      val (in_c1, in_c2, in_amt_sub) = (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))

      val newColName1_a = if (in_amt_sub < 0 && in_c1 == 0 && in_amt_sub < in_c2 &&  in_c2 != 0) {
        in_c2
      }
      else {
        in_c1
      }
      val newAmtSub_a = if (in_amt_sub != 0) {
        in_amt_sub - in_c2
      } else {
        in_amt_sub
      }

      val newColName1_b  = if (  newAmtSub_a  > 0 &&  newColName1_a  == 0 ) {
        in_c2  + newAmtSub_a
      } else {
        newColName1_a
      }

      val newAmtSub_b = if (newAmtSub_a  > 0  && newColName1_b   == 0) {
        0
      } else {
        newAmtSub_a
      }

      Seq(newColName1_b,  newAmtSub_b)
    }

  val colGeneratorUdf = udf(colGenerator)

  // Here the first column in the generated array is 'col4', the UDF could equivalently generate as many
  // other values as you want from the input array of column values.
  //
  val afterUdf = recs.withColumn("colsInStruct",   colGeneratorUdf (array($"col1", $"col2", $"amtToSubtract")))
  afterUdf.show()
  // RESULT
  //+----+----+-------------+------------+
  //|col1|col2|amtToSubtract|colsInStruct|
  //+----+----+-------------+------------+
  //|   1|   2|            3|      [1, 1]|
  //|  11|   2|            3|     [11, 1]|
  //+----+----+-------------+------------+


}
```

Comment: Appreciate your assistance. The challenge here is,
1. When-Otherwise logic are not the same for all 40 columns.
2. Major problem that I see here is - usage of iterative withColumns. So, integrating UDFs to this already performance degraded iterative withColumn code will only make this worse is what I understand.

Pls correct if my understanding is wrong. Nevertheless, already started trying the UDF option. Will keep you posted on the same.

Comment: Got it.  I think what you could do is move the logic for all the 40 columns inside your UDF.  Does that make sense?  If not... feel free to update your example with more logic for additional columns, and I can show you how you can move that to  a UDF if not clear.

Comment: Hi Chris, As requested - updated the question with the code that is reiterated many a times.

Comment: i updated the answer.. not sure i got your biz logic 100% correct.. but  hopefully should convey the general idea ;^)

Comment: @DasarathyDR - how did it go?  I'm curious as to whether you tried and performance improved.  hope it worked !

Comment: Oops! Apologies. Missed replying to your post. It worked like a charm. Performance has improved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DasarathyDR - i am glad it worked for you !   Please consider accepting the answer if you have time.   If you accept  it then  I get stack overflow points (which I imagine I can use for something one day!)    ;^)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the logic you're trying to apply. But here the idea of the foldleft:

```
  val colList = List("col1", "col2", "col3")
  val df: DataFrame = ???
  colList.foldLeft(df){case(df, colName1) => df
     .withColumn(colName1, when((col(amountToSubtract).<("0")) && (col(colName1).=== ("0")) && (col(amountToSubtract).<=(col(colName2))) && (col(colName2).!==("0")), col(colName2)).otherwise(col(colName1))).
     .withColumn(amountToSubtract, when(col(amountToSubtract).!==("0"), col(amountToSubtract).-(col(colName2))).otherwise(col(amountToSubtract))).
     .withColumn(colName1, when((col(amountToSubtract).>("0")) && (col(colName1).===("0")), col(colName2).+(col(amountToSubtract))).otherwise(col(colName1))).
     .withColumn(amountToSubtract, when((col(amountToSubtract).>("0")) && (col(colName1).===("0")), "0").otherwise(col(amountToSubtract)))
```

}